# time passed more than 1 week and less than 2 week

Tags: php, date

is it possible to do something like this.

i was trying to do it but couldn't...

this is what i was trying to do

```
    $date2second = strtotime('2013-03-5');
    $date1week = strtotime('2013-03-5') + 604800;

    //passed less than
    //$datetillnextweek = strtotime('2013-03-5') + 1209600;
    $datetillnextweek = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) + 1209600;

    echo "$date2second <br>";
    echo "$date1week <br>";
    echo "$datetillnextweek <br>";



    if($date2second < $date1week && $date2second <= $datetillnextweek)
    {
        echo "action";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$now = new DateTime('2013-03-28');
$one_week = new DateTime();
$one_week->modify('+1 week');
$two_weeks = new DateTime();
$two_weeks->modify('+2 weeks');
if ($now > $one_week && $now < $two_weeks)
{
    // you're here
}
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2roFJz)

Answer (score 1):

check the date add function and other date class options.  you can specify the interval and the format to present it .

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

```
<?php 
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01'); 
$date->add(new DateInterval('P7D')); 
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n"; 
?>
```

To see if its in a time period you can also use http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php to see if the difference iis larger then 7 days